# Better/faster way for changing React array state than cloning it?

Tags: reactjs

Whenever a React class has a state object that is or contains an array, updating that state feels awkward. Usually what I do is

```
var newArrayThing = _.clone(this.state.arrayThing); //or slice()
newArrayThing[123] = 42; //update stuff
this.setState({arrayThing: newArrayThing});
```

Is there a better or more elegant way of handling this I am missing? Especially since I always feel this is unnecessary slow if the array is big and the change is small. All that copying for a simple change. But the state should not be edited directly seems to be the mantra.

The Facebook docs mention the Immutability Helpers, but they seem even more far fetched than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a very idiomatic way to do it but if you have concerns over cloning large arrays, you should definitely look into the [update helper](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) that you mentioned, it's not really that bad:

```
this.setState({
  arrayThing: React.addons.update(this.state.arrayThing, {123: {$set: 42}})
})
```